# Damped harmonic oscillator's maximum displacement

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring, drag, oscillators

I want to know the maximum displacement $x_0$ of a mass $m$ on a spring with spring constant $k$, in the case that the system is damped with damping constant $c$, and where the initial velocity $v_0$ (at the equilibrium position) is known. Note that the following ODE describes my system (evolving over time $t$):

$$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -c\frac{dx}{dt} - kx$$

I'll assume that my system is under-damped, for which the equation of motion will be (take phase to be zero):

$$x(t) = x_0\exp\left(-\frac{c}{2m}t\right)\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{c^2-4mk}}{2m}t\right)$$

My initial condition: the mass is launched from equilibrium downward with initial velocity $v_0$. How can I identify the maximum displacement, $x_0$?

I suppose one should invoke energy conservation (if damping is not present, we can simply equate kinetic energy at equilibrium to potential energy at maximum displacement to find $x_0$), but how should one account for losses in energy due to damping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two known initial conditions, $x(0)$ and $v(0)$.  The general solution to the damped harmonic oscillator has two undetermined quantities, $x_0$ and the phase (or $A$ and $B$ if you prefer to write it in a different form [as is done here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/damped-harmonic-oscillators/)).  So, starting with the general form you can compute the position and velocity as a function of time, $x(t)$ and $v(t)=x'(t)$, and by plugging in $t=0$ relate the two unknowns to the initial conditions.  From there you have the general solution and can use calculus to compute the maximum value.